# Proving a value is the result of the execution of an algorithm

Tags: proof-techniques

Assuming an algorithm $A$ known to both Alice and Bob.

Alice runs the algorithm and gets a result $R$.
How can Alice prove to Bob that $R$ is the result of the execution of $A$ and not some random value (without having Bob run the algorithm himself)?

The goal is for Bob to perform less calculations checking Alice proof than running the algorithm itself. A probabilistic scheme for the proof is fine.

Please note that Alice does not have to prove correctness of $R$, just that she ran $A$ to obtain $R$.

The algorithm and its inputs can be modified to build the proof if necessary

Note: from the discussions below. I am happy with heuristics or techniques to obtain the proof. This is *not* a rhetorical question on algorithms.

Note2: @DavidRicherby suggests providing an execution trace, which seems perfectly reasonable. This leads to two sub-questions

1. How does Alice practically build a trace which proves to Bob with high probability that the trace is the one linked to the result ? (Bob should run less calculations checking the trace, than running the calculation himself)
2. Could such a mechanism be generic i.e. work with any algorithm ? For instance by confining execution inside a Virtual Machine which could record all operations.

Comment: The answer might depend on the program $P$.

Comment: Are you familiar with *interactive proofs*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Hello. Are you referring to Sigma protocols used in zero knowledge proofs for instance?

Comment: I have never heard of Sigma protocols. Zero-knowledge proofs are just one type of interactive proofs.

Comment: Either program $P$ or algorithm $A$ is an unnecessary variable. It is cleaner to just say "there is an algorithm $A$ that is known to both Alice and Bob". It looks like we should prefer an algorithm since it is more well defined than a program. Could you remove program P from the question?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Done. Does it help ? Please note that I can accept something to run "alongside" the algorithm, as long as I can strongly bind that "something" execution to the algorithm execution

Comment: As in the great tradition of Alan Turing, let $A$ be the simplest algorithm that always outputs 0. Does/can this question still make sense? Let $A$ be the algorithm that always outputs 1 minus input. Does/can this question still make sense? Let $A$ be the simplest random algorithm that outputs either 0 or 1 with equal probability. Does/can this question still make sense? For what kind of algorithm could this question make sense?

Comment: Yes, the question still makes sense. It does not matter that $A$ always outputs zero, what matters is that Alice can prove this result -zero-  was obtained by running $A$. So obviously a sort of proof of execution must be added to the result, but how ?

Comment: In fact, can you or anybody give one example that Alice can prove she ran A to obtain $R$ without having Bob run the algorithm himself in a way that is different from proving $R$ must come from a run of $A$ (but possibly by somebody else or by analyze $A$'s property or some other way)? Basically, I am asking for a formal definition the requirement.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific to get a meaningful answer. At the moment, the trivial answer of "Bob sends an execution trace of the algorithm" seems to fit perfectly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Great. How does Bob practically build such a trace proving with high probability that it is leading to the given result ? (I am making your comment part of the question for other readers to see easily)

Comment: @BGR What do you mean "with high probability"? The algorithm is executed by a Turing machine. Bob sends full details of every step the Turing machine took ("At the first step, the machine wrote "b", moved the head right and entered state $q$; at the second step, it wrote..."). Alice checks that this is a valid execution of the Turing machine. There is nothing probabilistic happening, here, and nothing probabilistic is mentioned in your question.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if Bob needs to check every step, it is as good as saying that Bob must run the algorithm himself, which is what we want to avoid. Maybe we could have Bob check some "checkpoints" only, which would reduce the amount of computation for Bob but then becomes probabilistic (which is fine)

Comment: @BGR (Er, I confused the roles of Alice and Bob but I don't think that's caused any problem). This is precisely why I say that you need to give more specifics in your question, and described my answer as "trivial". Nothing in your question prohibits the scheme I gave.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am not discounting your answer at all ! And I will be more specific. But yes, let us assume the calculation is very costly and Bob cannot spend the same cost checking Alice work

Comment: This question is actually two questions. The first is how to define the objective so that trivial solution is excluded and legit solution might be possible and should be interesting. The second is to find legit solutions. The two questions are interleaved very tightly, like when Cantor asked which infinity might be larger (successful) or when Hilbert asked how we could find solution to all Diophantine equations (not possible). So, "more specifics in your question" can be considered part of the answer. I do not believe OP has all the specifics nor can we formalize the objective yet.

Comment: It looks like "execution trace" could/should be abstracted and generalized as "side effect". That is, apart from (given some input) returning some result, the execution must have some side effect that can be used to prove the existence of execution (beyond small or any doubt).

Comment: By probabilistic checking, Do mean something like [probabilistic checkable proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistically_checkable_proof#Definition)?

Comment: Can this question be reworded "Given a program P and a putative result R, how can it be verified that P would actually result in R, using less resources that running P"? Are you trying to distinguish between putative results that match the output versus putative results that don't? Or, given an output that matches what the program would output, are you trying to distinguish between cases where that output was obtained by running the program versus someone just randomly having a lucky guess?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion.  Please edit the question to incorporate the relevant clarifications into the post itself, then flag as 'no longer needed' all the comments that have been rendered obsolete.

Comment: @Acccumulation the second one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is known as [verifiable computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verifiable_computing) or verified computation.  There are many protocols for verified computation, with different properties.  Some of them rely upon special hardware (e.g., SGX).  Many of them don't rely on special hardware and use cryptography.  Among the cryptographic solutions, there are some protocols that can be used with any program (but are potentially inefficient), and some that can only be used for specific programs or types of computations (but are much more efficient).

There's an entire line of research papers on the subject, and it is too broad to summarize in a single paragraph or two.  I suggest reading about interactive proofs, and about the [Pepper](https://www.pepper-project.org/), [Ginger](https://www.pepper-project.org/ginger-usec12-v2.pdf), [Zaatar](http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/622), [Pinocchio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/verifiable-computing/?from=http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fprojects%2Fverifcomp%2F), [Pantry](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/356), and [Truebit](https://truebit.io/) systems, among others.  I also recommend reading the following survey paper for an overview of cryptographic solutions that can handle general computation:

- [Verifying computations without reexecuting them](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2728770.2641562), Michael Walfish, Andrew J. Blumberg, CACM 58(2), February 2015.

In practice, I suspect that the SGX-based schemes or Truebit are likely to be the most practical for general computation at the moment, though the research literature is progressing rapidly and this could change in the future.  For specific computations, it is sometimes possible to design a custom protocol that does much better, but that depends on the particular computation.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I have started reviewing the literature which is usually targeting correctness  as well. I was hoping that by relaxing requirements I could get a more practical implementation: I am only trying to distinguish random values from a value - correct or not - outputted by the algorithm; a sort of "proof of work"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the algorithm results in an output $R$ that is a deterministic function of its input(s).

Bob asks Alice to run the algorithm on a given input $I$, obtain an output $R_1$, use that as an input to the algorithm and produce $R_2$, and to re-run the algorithm $n$ number of times where $n$ is an even number. Bob also asks Alice to send  $R_{n/2}$ and $R_n$

Now Bob runs the algorithm $\frac{n}{2}$ times on the initial input $I$ (with $p=0.5$) and checks if $A(A(A(..I))) = R_{n/2}$ or runs it on $R_{n/2}$ (with $p=0.5$) and sees if $A(A(A(..R_{n/2}))) = R_n$.

As suggested by @Draconis, we can also extend this to any $k$ instead of looking at just 2 results. This will allow Bob to potentially do much lesser work.

We can use a probability bound to see what the value of $n$ should be to obtain a given confidence. This way, Bob can be certain that Alice is running algorithm $A$ by using fewer computations that Alice.

Note: This relies on Bob asking Alice to do possibly meaningless extra computations but do let me know if there are specific points in your question that this answer does not address.

Comment: You can also replace the 2 with some arbitrary $k$ to make Bob do potentially *much* less work, though no matter what $k$ is (even for 2) you should use this algorithm several times to get a solid p-value.

Comment: Yep that sounds good! Thank you @Draconis

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why it would ever be beneficial to choose $n>2$ -- could you elaborate please?  (I *can* see why running the entire procedure multiple times is useful to reduce the probability of a false positive.)

Comment: Unfortunately this method works poorly.  Alice can cheat, in a way that causes her to be detected with low probability.  With your initial example, Alice can pick a single step and replace the internal state with some other state (cheating); this will be detected only if Bob happens to pick the same half that Alice cheated on to recompute.  So with that example, Alice's cheating is detected with probability only $1/2$.  That's usually not good enough in practice -- if Alice can fool you half of the time, you've got a serious problem.

Comment: If you split into $k$ pieces (instead of 2) and you recompute $r$ of them, then the probability that Alice's cheating is discovered is only $r/k$.  Meanwhile, the work that Bob has to do is a $r/k$ fraction of the work that Bob would have to do of the entire task.  If you want the probability of detecting cheating to be very close to 1 (which you typically will, in practice), you need $r/k$ to be close to 1, which means that Bob has to do essentially as much work as if he just computed the answer himself without Alice's help.  For that reason, this method is a poor solution to the problem.